# Missing Anaconda Navigator and command prompt in the Start Menu

Tags: python, keras, anaconda

I am having multiple problem installing the anaconda on Windows 10.

First I cant see Anaconda Navigator in the Start Menu.

Second if I navigate to the installation Directory :

C:\Users\user-name\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3 I can see the bin folder there.

Below is the Snapshot

[image]

I also cant see the Anaconda Prompt

C:\Users\user-name\conda
'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I have tried re-installing the python,anaconda many times.

**Do I need to install the Python before ?Which Version?3.7 or latest(3.8) .**

Also I doubt the Installation is Complete (by looking at the anaconda3 folder.Can someone who has successfully installed Anaconda , please check)

Comment: hello, can you try downloading from this link https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/.

Comment: I did that only

Comment: I've tried several different `Anaconda3-xxxx.xx-Windows-x86_64.exe` on https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/ from 2019 to 2020 and finally I found Anaconda3-2019.03-Windows-x86_64.exe works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can install any later version of Python 3 
Install conda 
set the environment variable for both Python and Anaconda

After setting the environment variable open a new command prompt and try conda install

Comment: Which environment variables must be set for Python and Anaconda? Do you mean the PATH variable? Can you share how will installing conda from command prompt may help with issues around anaconda?

Comment: Yeah setting the path variable. As per your comment you are facing conda not recognized error so, Uninstall the Anaconda exe and install it again and check